# How to use django logging handlers behind gunicorn?

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn

I'm running a django app behind gunicorn and nginx and the django app is configured with a logger that uses several different handlers. I was surprised to find out that when I run the gunicorn (instead of `runserver`). The logging handlers I configured in `settings.py` don't work. Am I missing something here or is this supposed to happen? If so, then how can I force gunicorn to use the handlers and logging config I have in the django app?

Here is my logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] {%(module)s} [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/info.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default' 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['default', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        }
    }
}

LOKI_HOST = os.environ.get('LOKI_HOST')

if LOKI_HOST is not None:
    print(f'Adding loki logger with host {LOKI_HOST}')
    # add the loki handlers
    LOGGING['handlers']['loki'] = {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging_loki.LokiHandler',
        'url': f'http://{LOKI_HOST}:3100/loki/api/v1/push',
        'tags':  {'app': 'django', 'env': ENV},
        'version': '1',
    }

    # configure loggers to use loki
    LOGGING['loggers']['']['handlers'].append('loki')
    LOGGING['loggers']['django']['handlers'].append('loki')
```

Comment: What are your handlers? Logging should work normally, gunicorn has nothing to do with it. "force gunicorn to use the handlers and logging config" makes no sense. If any of your django code produces logging, it uses your LOGGING settings. If gunicorn itself produces logging, it logs to the file you specify in the gunicorn settings (setting `errorlog` in your configuration file), see [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#logging)

Comment: @dirkgroten I have a handler that saves logs to files and one that streams them to loki and neither of them are working

Comment: @dirkgroten Clarification: I just noticed that only the default django logger is not working (it doesn't send its logs to the handlers I have specified)

Comment: I think you should put your root logger (`''`) **after** more specific loggers, so switch them (`'django'` before `''`)

Comment: @dirkgroten its not making a difference

Comment: Your logging config looks fine to me. If it works for your own logging calls, it should also work for logging calls by django. Can you give an example of a logging entry you created that works and one that you'd expect but don't see?

Comment: I think this may be a bug in gunicorn. I added this same dict in a gunicorn conf file and the logging is working as expected. It seems that without the conf file the logging configuration in settings.py is completely ignored